# Compiling Python project in C++. How do I include linked library

Tags: python, c, swig

Hi fellow stackoverflowers,

I want to compile a SWIG project with g++ using following command:

```
g++ -shared python/swig_wrap.o  -IC:/Python27/include/ -lpython2.7 -o python/_lib.so
```

Unfortunately, g++ or rather ld.exe complains that it can't find -lpython2.7

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython2.7
```

How do I specify where the library resides on my hard drive or do I have to compile it first from the python source?

Comment: Honestly, I'm surprised it can even find `ld.exe`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
g++ -shared python/swig_wrap.o  -IC:/Python27/include/ -LC:/Python27/libs -lpython27 -o python/_lib.so
```

It should normally work.

Comment: Okay, kind of worked. The lib file is named python27, so I had to change that part too. Thanks nonetheless.